# Will a pointer-event:none save "CLS" score in Core Web Vitals?

Tags: core-web-vitals, cumulative-layout-shift, web-vitals

I have a page with high CLS scores, due to some dynamically loaded content.

The UI/UX is good and no users ever complained about it, but the lower part of the page contains consumes a lot of room.

Will a `pointer-event:none` on the lower DOM elements save "CLS" score in Core Web Vitals?

Comment: Can you explain why you think `pointer-event:none` will help here? I'm struggling to make the connection.

Comment: Because IMO, Google should punish the content shift that actually interfere user's actions, like click, tap, mousemove, etc. Adding  `pointer-event:none` is telling Google, "hey, the DOM are not interaction elements". Sometimes, it's really hard to avoid CLS, for instance, I want to load an external comment system, I can set a "click to load comment", but after clicking that button, the data will take a few seconds to deliver, and that would cause a CLS, in that case, there's no way for me to avoid CLS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The UI/UX is good and no users ever complained about it, but the lower part of the page contains consumes a lot of room.

You'd be surprised how many people don't complain, but still find layout shifts annoying and bad UX.

> Will a pointer-event:none on the lower DOM elements save "CLS" score in Core Web Vitals?

In the comments you added to this saying "IMO, Google should punish the content shift that actually interfere user's actions, like click, tap, mousemove, etc.".

CLS measures all items moving - whether it interferes with interactions or not. For example, one of the most annoying instances of CLS is when an article loads and you start reading, and then other content (an image, an ad...etc.) loads above it and the text shifts and you lose your place. There are no interactions there but the shifts are a bad experience. Hence are included in CLS.

In fact, CLS actually gives you some leeway for interactions by [excluding shifts after certain interactions](https://web.dev/cls/#expected-vs-unexpected-layout-shifts), as some interactions are expected to cause shifts. For example, clicking a summary/details element will show more content and shift it down - but that's an expected shift that will not annoy the user.

So in answer to your question, not using `pointer-event:none` will not "save 'CLS' scores".

Comment: Hi Barry, thanks very much for your informative reply and suggestions. I read the `hadRecentInput` part. Looks like I need to upgrade the product design for a better approach. Thanks again